# How do I make the Android Cardview appear like Android now? (align bottom)

Tags: android, xamarin, android-cardview

I am trying to make an android view where there is an image at the top, with text at the bottom, similar to the Android now cards.

I'm having issues taking the "command" buttons and aligning them below all the text, ideally separated by a HR line.

Here is the code I've been working with, and unable to make it look like the [android Now cards](http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/06/google_now_android.png) -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_view_inner_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:textColor="#0000FF"
                android:id="@+id/personaTextView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/image_view"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Some text here" />

            <TextView
                android:textColor="#00FFFF"
                android:id="@+id/personaTextView2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/personaTextView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/image_view"
                android:text="Some text here" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:src="@android:drawable/btn_radio" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View    
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <RelativeLayout         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cardAction1"
                android:textColor="#00FFFF"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Action 1"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cardAction2"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cardAction2"
                android:textColor="#00FFFF"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Action 2"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            />

         </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The problem I'm (now) having is that I can't get the action buttons to work

[image]

Comment: Can you be more precise? What is not working with the 2 buttons? You mean they are not visible or no action is fired?

Comment: @jj86 Thank you, I was able to get this to work... took a bit of fiddling with the nested layouts, but it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_view_inner_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/image_view"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Some text here" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text_view1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/image_view"
                android:text="Some text here" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:src="@android:drawable/btn_radio" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Some random text" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Neat trick on the horizontal line.  I was reading somewhere that Linear layouts cause issues (slower performance), is this true?

Comment: LinearLayout can result in bad performance if you make very deep hierarchy (LinearLayout inside LinearLayout inside LinearLayout and more). Using RelativeLayout you can solve this problem and reduce hierarchy. But LinearLayouts is simple so here it's good enought, no need to use RelativeLayout instead of it, because you have 3 items, one under below. I could put all items in RelativeLayout, but I decided to separate top (above line), because text can be higher than image and vice versa.

Comment: If you want add `Button`, you can place it instead of `TextView` under horizontal line like @JJ86 answered - `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` will give you flat button.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a **flat button** like this in your view (see [this link](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#)):

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your text"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
/>
```

Then, of course, is up to you to design your `View`.